Shaka-Player - HLS FairPlay license not fetched
I'm using shaka-player (@4.10) and I'm trying to play a stream on Safari with my Mac.
I've configured the player as following :
const certificateUri = '';
const streamUri = '';
const licenseUri = '';

var player = new shaka.Player();

...

player.configure({
    drm: {
        servers: {
            'com.apple.fps.1_0': licenseUri
        },
        advanced: {
            'com.apple.fps.1_0': {
                serverCertificateUri: certificateUri
            }
        }
    }
});

await player.load(manifestUri);


Unfortunately, it seems that the license is not fetched since I'm not able to see any request when registering a request filter on my player's network engine. What's wrong ?
